# Create an horizontal description list from a json object

Tags: javascript, html, json

The structure I plan to have is an horizontal description list like

```
 key    key2  ...

value  value2 ...
```

My code is:

html:

```
<dl class="horizonal_list">
  <dt>Key</dt>
  <dd>Value</dd>
</dl>
<dl class="horizonal_list">
  <dt>Another key</dt>
  <dd>Another value</dd>
</dl>
...
```

css:

```
dt, dd {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align:center;
}

.horizonal_list {
float: left;
}
```

Basically, I'd like to show into the above horizontal list some information retrieved from the server and then sent to a JSON object, like the following:

```
var current_status = {"REFERENCE":"1000006",
                        "NUMBER":108,
                        "DESCRIPTION":"SC1B",
                        "CONFIRMATION":"155248",
                        "CREATION_DATE":15584,
                        "YEAR":2013,
                        "NDOQ":161,
                        "NEZC":"161",
                        "STATUS":"LI"};
```

But, I'm very new to web dev and I'd like some tips. Thanks.

Comment: so you want to create a table... use a table, tables are **not** bad for displaying structured data (as opposed to using them for layout purposes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each property in your object, and then add a new `<dl>` element for each key/value pair.

NOTE that this example JQuery for appending the html to the DOM.

```
function addItem(key, value) {
    $("div").append('<dl class="horizonal_list"><dt>' + key + '</dt><dd>' + value + '</dd></dl>');
}

for (var key in current_status) {
    addItem(key, current_status[key]);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ83Y/)

---

In the example above, `<div>` has been used to represent an empty container that each `<dl>` element will be added to. This may be different from what you current have so you will need to change that accordingly.

If you are going to be calling this function more than once you will want to clear the `<div>` element each time before you populate it:

```
$("div").empty();
```

[Here is a more realistic example](http://jsfiddle.net/hQ83Y/1/), which shows how to update the data on demand

Comment: seems quite nice! I'll give it a try immediately. (about jQuery, even though I'm very beginner, I understood it's the first thing to link in your js code :-) ) Thanks again for the live example!!! If I need to refer to a div in particular I need `#div_id`, don't I?